# Что означают квадратные скобки без чего-либо с других сторон?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция

```
function addEdge(from, to) {
    if(graph[from] == null) {
        graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
        graph[from].push(to);
    }
}
```

Я не пойму что в данном случает означает `[to]`. Я знаю что graph[from] означает взять элемент по индексу from из массива graph. Но в случает с `[to]` никаких массивов с левой стороны нету. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует два варианта синтаксиса для создания массива:

```
const arr = new Array();
const arr = [];
```

Практически всегда используется второй вариант синтаксиса. В скобках мы можем указать начальные значения элементов:

```
const fruits = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Слива"];
```

Больше о массивах в `JS` вы можете прочитать здесь - [Массивы](https://learn.javascript.ru/array)

Comment: Пишет только через шесть минут можно галку поставить. Поставлю обязательно. Не переживатйе

Comment: Необходимо писать `const`

Comment: @doox911 необходимо? почему так догматично?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  так как там хранится ссылка на массив. В примере с `fruits` лучше написать `const`, так как ссылка не меняется. Соглашусь, что комментарий был не многословен. Я имел в виду, что *лучше* - `const`.

Comment: @doox911, как вы по одной строчке определили, что ссылка не меняется? Далее по коду может требоваться изменение ссылки (запись другого массива в переменную).

Comment: @PavelGrishaev а с чего вы взяли, что они есть? Я вижу, что их нет.

Comment: " а с чего вы взяли, что они есть?" - не понял кто они. Если рассматривать только одну строку и других строк нет, то этой переменной вообще не будет, браузер освободит память или вообще проигнорирует строку.